# node.js how to insert string to beginning of file but not replace the original text?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

The code below inserted `somestring` to file but also will replace the text inside the file. how can fix this?

```
fd = fs.openSync('file', 'r+')
buf = new Buffer('somestring')
fs.writeSync(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0)
fs.close(fd)
```

Comment: [I personally found this answer to be better in terms of elegance and being intuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636121/3942699)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open the file in append mode using the `a+` flag

```
var fd = fs.openSync('file', 'a+');
```

Or use a positional `write`. To be able to append to end of file, use `fs.appendFile`:

```
fs.appendFile(fd, buf, err => {
  //
});
```

Write to the beginning of a file:

```
fs.write(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0);
```

**EDIT:**

I guess there isn't a single method call for that. But you can copy the contents of the file, write new data, and append the copied data.

```js
var data = fs.readFileSync(file); //read existing contents into data
var fd = fs.openSync(file, 'w+');
var buffer = Buffer.from('New text');

fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0); //write new data
fs.writeSync(fd, data, 0, data.length, buffer.length); //append old data
// or fs.appendFile(fd, data);
fs.close(fd);
```

Please note that you must use the asynchronous versions of these methods if these operations aren't performed just once during initialization, as they'll block the event loop.

Comment: hi c.P.u1 thanks for your reply but what I want is insert to beginning of the file not append to end of the file

Comment: fs.write(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, 0); will overwrite the original text inside the file even with `a+`

Comment: @DevPiplay, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I think last line: fs.writeSync(fd, data, 0, data.length); should be: fs.writeSync(fd, data, buffer.length, data.length); because third parameter means the offset where the write begins. Then it actually makes the append.

Comment: The following line is wrong: 
fs.writeSync(fd, data, buffer.length, data.length);
it should be :
fs.writeSync(fd, data, 0, data.length,buffer.length);
the third and fourth param are offset and length determine the part of the buffer to be written, you need an extra param for the position in the file from which to write

Answer (score 7):

With small files you can do it like this:

```
let logPath = path.join(appPath, 'deploy.log');
let logRows = fs.readFileSync(logPath).toString().split('\n');

logRows.unshift('Your string here');
fs.writeFileSync(logPath, logRows.join('\n'));
```

Hope it would be useful for someone!