# Add string on top file with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, fs

I would like add string on the top of my js file. Actuly, it's on the end :

```
var file = './public/js/app.bundleES6.js',
    string = '// My string';

    fs.appendFileSync(file, string);
```

Do you have idea for add my string on the first line ?

Thank you !

Comment: https://github.com/coderaiser/node-prepend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no built-in way to insert at the beginning of the file in Node.js.

But you can use `readFileSync` and `writeFile` methods of `fs` to resolve this issue

> It will `append` string at top of the file

Try this

### Method#1

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('./example.js').toString().split("\n");
data.splice(0, 0, "Append the string whatever you want at top" );
var text = data.join("\n");

fs.writeFile('./example.js', text, function (err) {
  if (err) return err;
});
```

### Method#2

If you are relying on to use third party module then you can use [prepend](https://github.com/coderaiser/node-prepend) module to add the string at the top as suggested by @robertklep.

```
var prepend = require('prepend');

prepend(FileName, 'String to be appended', function(error) {
    if (error)
        console.error(error.message);
});
```

Comment: I've try the first method, but on the end my file is empty. For the second method, i'm not view the string in my file :(

Comment: What does it mean? string is added in targeted file or not?
Since it works for me

Comment: String isn't added in targeted file. I add this code on simple grunt task, but no result, and not console.log displayed.

Comment: Can you check it without grunt? like in separate js file.Since both method works for me as my expected

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: I don't think splitting, splicing, and rejoining is necessary if you want to add text to the beginning (it is though if you want to add within the file content), you can just use string concatenation. Also the `prepend` package pretty much does what your method #1 does, so I'd recommend implementing this yourself rather than install a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const oldData = fs.readFileSync('./example.js').toString()
const newData = completeChangelog + oldData
fs.writeFileSync('./example.js'`, newData)
```